# How to find center of a marker in an accurate way?

Tags: c++, opencv, markers

I want to get the value of the center of the marker. as a picture below.

[image: The center that I want]

I have tried to calculate the center of the marker by calculating from the corner of the marker. So, I already got the center of the marker but it was not accurate values as I want. When the marker is not parallel to a camera, the calculated center has shifted from the center of the marker as a picture below.

[image: the calculated center from the corner]

I would appreciate if you could give me some suggestions to find the center of the marker in an accuracy way.

I would like to apologize if my question is not clear enough. 
Please let me know what I have to improve.

Comment: What are your conditions for the sheet? In your photo, it looks like the sheet is not only in an angle to the camera but also in an arc - after all, the space between the inner white and the edge of the black square seems to be bigger on the left than on the right in the pixels of the photo, but not on your first image. Before we think about algorithms how to counter such distortions, we need to know what distortions we have to expect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I think I don't have expected distortion. Distortion of the marker depends on the camera view. I just need the center of the marker whenever the marker has detected by camera.

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is at an angle, you can use a [perspective transform](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/01/perspective-transform.html) to obtain a bird's eye view of the image. To obtain the center of the marker, you can first find the corners using the [Shi-Tomasi Corner Detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d8/dd8/tutorial_good_features_to_track.html) or the [Harris corner detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d7d/tutorial_harris_detector.html) and then use geometry calculations based on the found corners to obtain your center point.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I will try it.